# Is it possible to sync between Line Chart and Scattered Chart in Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a scattered and a line chart type. I am trying to sync between these charts type.
I have these problems:

1. the tooltip does not appear in scattered chart when I hover to line chart, but the "cursor line" sync
2. when I hover in the scattered chart, there is no sync between line and scattered chart

the details can be seen here:
[image: Recording 2022-10-18 at 10 41 24]

here is the code I have

```
const Chart = ({ type, matrixData, index, diagcodeLabel }) => {
    const getMinValue = Math.min(...matrixData.map((data) => data[type]));
    const getMaxValue = Math.max(...matrixData.map((data) => data[type]));

    return (
        <div className="chart">
            <div className="title">{type}</div>
            <ResponsiveContainer key={"responsiveInformation"} width="100%" height={170}>
                {type === "DIAGCODE" ? (
                    <ScatterChart
                        syncId="chart"
                        width={1200}
                        height={400}
                        margin={{
                            top: 20,
                            right: 20,
                            bottom: 20,
                            left: 20,
                        }}
                    >
                        <YAxis
                            type="number"
                            dataKey="dLevel"
                            tickFormatter={(value) => {
                                return Object.keys(diagcodeLabel).find((k) => diagcodeLabel[k] === value);
                            }}
                        />
                        <Tooltip />
                        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" className="chartGrid" />

                        <Legend layout="vertical" content={<CustomLegend />} />
                        <Scatter name="DiagCode" data={matrixData} fill="#8884d8" shape={"circle"}>
                            {matrixData.map((entry, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <Cell
                                        key={"cell-${index}"}
                                        fill={entry.IsLockout === "Lockout" ? "#5fb0ff" : "rgb(172, 45, 45)"}
                                    />
                                );
                            })}
                        </Scatter>
                    </ScatterChart>
                ) : (
                    <LineChart
                        syncId="chart"
                        width={500}
                        height={50}
                        data={matrixData}
                        margin={{
                            top: 5,
                            right: 30,
                            left: 20,
                            bottom: 5,
                        }}
                    >
                        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" className="chartGrid" />
                        <YAxis dataKey={type} domain={[getMinValue, getMaxValue]} />
                        <Tooltip />
                        <Line type="monotone" dataKey={type} stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{ r: 8 }} />
                    </LineChart>
                )}
            </ResponsiveContainer>
        </div>
    );};
```

Is there a way I could sync them ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of feature is underdevelopment https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1541

So, I ended up using composed charts (Scattered and Bar) https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/LineBarAreaComposedChart and I set the fillOpacity transparent for Bar. but I am not sure if it is the best workaround...